# Access denied by Remove-Item

Tags: windows, terminal, powershell

I am using `PowerShell` of Windows 10.

This might be so basic question.

I can't delete the folder by `Remove-Item`.

```
PS C:\Users\whitebear> Remove-Item MQL_Set.

+ remove-item MQL_Set
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\whitebear\MQL_Set:String) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

However there is a folder.

```
PS C:\Users\whitebear> dir

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-r---       2021/01/22      0:20                3D Objects
d-r---       2021/01/22      0:20                Contacts
d-r---       2021/05/06     16:46                Desktop
d-r---       2020/05/10      4:07                Documents
d-r---       2021/05/03      0:49                Downloads
d-r---       2021/01/22      0:20                Favorites
d-r---       2021/01/22      0:20                Links
d-----       2021/05/09     11:14                MQL_Set
```

I am not familiar with `PowerShell`

Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesn’t appear like you have permissions to the folder.  You are running the command as an Administrator, and the folder is owned by the user, running the command?

Answer (score 1):

Permission denied in Powershell cases can be avoided with running PowerShell as an administrator.

- Click Win-R and type PowerShell.
- Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter to run it as an administrator.
- Press yes on the UAC window, allowing changes to be made.
- Run your command again using this new Admin window.

Comment: You have to take ownership of the file tree before you can delete even as admin. That's my understanding